# Navigation submenus not displaying correctly for specific main nav link

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not entirely sure what's happening but, for this 3-level nav I'm working on, the second link doesn't display the submenus correctly. If you hover over "Products" in my codepen example, you'll see a third-tier submenu item appear, which is not correct. As you hover over links in the second tier, some third tier menu items show when they shouldn't. The first link, "About Us" appears to work fine, though, so I'm confused.

https://codepen.io/gojiHime/pen/ymVNgW

```
let topLevel = $("li.menu-item-has-children > a");
let topLevelElement = $(".nav > li.menu-item-has-children");
let subMenuInnerLink = $(
  ".nav > li.menu-item-has-children > ul.sub-menu:first-of-type > li"
);
let navContainer = $("nav.nav-primary");

$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() >= 768) {
    //TOGGLING SUBMENU NAVIGATION
    subMenuInnerLink.hover(
      function() {
        $("ul", this)
          .stop()
          .slideDown(200);
        if (
          $(this)
            .children("ul")
            .offset().left +
            200 >
          $(window).width()
        ) {
          $(this)
            .children("ul")({ right: "180px" })
            .animate({ right: "0px" }, "slow");
        }
      },
      function() {
        $("ul", this)
          .stop()
          .slideUp(200);
      }
    );
  } else {
    subMenuInnerLink.unbind("mouseenter mouseleave");
    subMenuInnerLink.on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  }
});

if (getWindowWidth() >= 768) {
  //TOGGLING SUBMENU NAVIGATION
  topLevelElement.each(function() {
    $(this).hover(
      function() {
        $(this)
          .children(".sub-menu")
          .stop()
          .slideDown(200);
      },
      function() {
        $(this)
          .children(".sub-menu")
          .stop()
          .slideUp(200);
      }
    );
  });

  subMenuInnerLink.hover(
    function() {
      $("ul", this)
        .stop()
        .slideDown(200);
    },
    function() {
      $("ul", this)
        .stop()
        .slideUp(200);
    }
  );
} else {
  subMenuInnerLink.unbind("mouseenter mouseleave");
  subMenuInnerLink.on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
}

function getWindowWidth() {
  var windowWidth = 0;
  if (typeof window.innerWidth == "number") {
    windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
  } else {
    if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientWidth) {
      windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    } else {
      if (document.body && document.body.clientWidth) {
        windowWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
      }
    }
  }
  return windowWidth;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your third-level menu is not hidden by default.
The styles you've provided in the CodePen example do hide the second-level menu, however, line 62 explicitly allows them to be visible:

```
.sub-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

If we change that do `display: none`, we'll get the desired outcome.

Here is an [updated sample](https://codepen.io/jasonrammoray/pen/pMNbVN) on CodePen.

One last thing - I noticed runtime error in your code that sometimes happen when you calculate the left offset and add 200 to it (row 19).
You might want to fix that before the production deploy.